# Create Google Form from a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to create a Google Form via its API. The form has a template. So, I'm looking for a method to either **clone** existing form or to **create** a form **from a template**.

By now I didn't manage to find related method, so I just manually copy items from one form to another, this is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the Drive API to [copy a file using its ID](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) or in Apps script with:

```
function copyFileFunction() {
  var fileToCopy = DriveApp.getFilesById(‘fileId’).next();
  fileToCopy.makeCopy();
}
```